# Prestashop 1.7 -To avoid internationalization data inconsistencies upgrade the symfony/intl component

Tags: symfony, prestashop-1.7

Prestashop 1.7 gives following warning during installation:
`To avoid internationalization data inconsistencies upgrade the symfony/intl component.`

How do I upgrade `symfony/intl` on Ubuntu Ubuntu 16.04?

Tried:

`composer update` in the prestashop folder, received `Composer could not find a composer.json file`

Currently I ignored this warning, is it safe to ignore it, what side effects I should expect?

Answer (score 4):

Symfony relies on the ICU (International Components for Unicode) and ideally you want your version to match the version they require.

1. First, [check what is the latest version of the ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/download) available, as off June 2019, this is v64.2.
2. Check which version of the ICU you are currently running with `php -i` and look for your the `intl` section where you will find the ICU version you are running.
3. Finally, check which version of the ICU you will need, based on your PrestaShop version:

1.7.5.x   -   ICU v63.1 
1.7.4.x   -   ICU v62.1
1.7.3.x   -   ICU v60.1
1.7.2.x   -   ICU v59.1
1.7.1.x   -   ICU v58.2
1.7.0.x   -   ICU v57.1`

**Ok, once you have figured that out, let's upgrade your ICU to the right version, the one matching your PrestaShop version.**

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/installation/system-requirements/

Find which version of the php-intl package you are currently running:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep '\-intl'
```

In my case it was `php7.2-intl`, remove it:

```
sudo apt-get remove php7.2-intl
```

Install phpize:

```
sudo apt install php7.2-dev
```

Next, download this script that will assist us and set the right permissions:

```
sudo wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/siffash/76676186de0ffc6eb6cbf89abc7a5e2f/raw/e45838b09ffa0700c6134f1b2da69884773aadc9/icu-install.sh
sudo chmod +x ./icu-install.sh
```

Check the available releases:

```
sudo ./icu-install.sh versions
```

Download and Install the version you are interested in (62.1 in our case), this step can take a while (~10-15min), depending on your server capabilities:

```
sudo ./icu-install.sh install v62.1
```

Once successfully completed, let's edit 20-intl.ini:

```
sudo touch /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini && sudo bash -c 'echo "extension=intl.so" > /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini' && sudo touch /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-intl.ini && sudo bash -c 'echo "extension=intl.so" > /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-intl.ini'
```

Restart Apache2:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Let's clean up by removing the install folder and phpize:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove php7.2-dev
rm -rf /tmp/icu-install
```

Finally, let's check again our current version of the ICU with `php -i`.

You should now be all set, I hope this helps!

Comment: The command to install the right version of icu has a error typo, it must be: sudo ./icu-install.sh install 62.1 (without v)